# Javascript If array element contains a period

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, split

I want this to search through an array I've made from a string, then if it has a period at the end of the element, I would like it to randomly (50% chance) add "Arr!" before the next sentence. My problem is, I don't quite know how to check if there is a period at the end of the given array element. I'm guessing that regular expressions would be best, but I'm terrible with them... would anyone be able to provide some insight??

```
var Things = output2.value.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < Things.length; i++) {
  Things[i] += " ";
  if (Things[i]==".") {
    var randnumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1)
    if (randnumb == 1) {
      Things[i] += " Arr!"
    };
  } 
};
```

Comment: regex are probably not needed if all you want to do is check for a period at the end of a string see below for some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex will be very inefficient.

```
var stringToCheck = 'something';
var period = '.';

//check if string ends with period (.)
if (stringToCheck.indexOf(period, this.length - period.length) !== -1)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after some slight modifications! Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `stringToCheck[stringToCheck.length - 1] === '.'` or `stringToCheck.slice(-1) === '.'`?

Comment: @bjb568 I said regex will be "inefficient", hence there is no regex. plalx's suggestions are better option for single character. The answer I suggested will work for single character or string.

Answer (score 3):

Regex are probably not needed if *all you want to do* is check for a period at the end of a string:

```
var lastChar = Things[i].substr(Things[i].length - 1); 
if( lastChar === "." ) {
    ...
}
```

Instead you can use `substr()` - the substring function to get a substring containing just the last character of `Things[i]` based on the length of `Things[i]` as shown above.

[Here's a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to more info on substr().

Comment: Why was this link edited from W3Schools.com to the MDN?

Answer (score 0):

A simple RegEx would be `/\.$/`

The `$` symbol represents the end of a string, so this RegEx matches any `.` right befor the end of a string.

### Example

```js
var string1 = 'something';
// does NOT end with period

var string2 = 'something.';
// DOES end with period

if (/\.$/.exec(string1)) {
  document.write('string1 ends with a period.');
} else {
  document.write('string1 DOES NOT end with a period.');
}

document.write('<br/><br/>');

if (/\.$/.exec(string2)) {
  document.write('string2 ends with a period.');
} else {
  document.write('string2 DOES NOT end with a period.');
}
```